# Send 2 input form fields entries as one value

Tags: html

I am having an issues sending a range for my post data.

I want "price" to post as: ...price=value1:value2

I am using text input fields.

However, I am not sure how to get "value2" in the post as shown above.

This is what I have now:

```
 <input id="price1" type="number" name="price" value="200000" />

 <input id="price2" type="number" name="max" value="12000000" />
```

Currently this will post as price=200000&max=12000000

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using javascript to update the value of a 3rd field. Which should probably be hidden to not change the current UI you have.

http://codepen.io/justindunham/pen/BADpf

```
var updatePrice = function() {      
  var range = document.getElementById('priceRange');
  var low = document.getElementById('price1');
  var high = document.getElementById('price2');
  range.value = low.value + ":" + high.value;      
};
```

Comment: This worked great! Question, how would I set the default value? If I just submit, it post priceRange with no value... I tried placeholder="..." but that didn't work

Comment: Just figured it out, I just set value="value1;Value2" for id=priceRange and that worked! Thanks!

Comment: I would just set a value on your hidden html field. This way if the function is never triggered there is still a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You cant, if you have 2 inputs, the post action will post 2 separated values.

You could add only 1 input and with javascript append the value of a second input to the first one, so you will post 1 field with a text value like "value1:value2" , like if you had

```
<input id="price1" type="number" name="price" value="200000:12000000" />
```

Comment: I see. So would it look something like this? 

<script type="text/javascript">    
document.max.value = "my value";
</script>

Comment: I use JQuery, it should be something like: 
var price1 = $('#price1').val();
var price2 = $('#price2').val();
$('#price1').val(price1 + ":" + price2);
 But I don't think why you should need to do something like this. You can post both inputs and then do something with those 2 values...